# Displaying warning message when check box is checked in JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp, dojo

In my jsp page,among other input fields, I have two Check boxes in the top and two drop downs at the end of the page which has values such as 'One' and 'Two' among many other values. On checking the two check boxes ,I want a warning message to be displayed next to each of the drop down boxes as 'One or Two must be selected' and on unchecking those two check boxes the warning message should disappear.

Similarly when the user does not select either of 'One' or 'Two' in the dropdowns when the check box is selected , the same warning message should appear.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you can use jquery change event for checking the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `div` tag next to each of your drop down boxes. Make the `div` tags shown by default and display your text inside. Call a function on change of the check box values a based on the selection decide whether to hide/show the `div` tags.